# Access powershell with elevated access using Node.js

Tags: node.js, powershell, iis, hosting, playwright

I want to access powershell with elevated access through Node.js.

The main task is to edit bindings of IIS through Node.js. I have found a powershell script to edit the bindings but I can't make it run through Node.js using the child-process. The access permissions is the issue.

I tried the following script:

```
const { spawn } = require("child_process");

const powershell = spawn("powershell.exe", [
  "Import-Module WebAdministration"
]);

powershell.stdout.on("data", data => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

powershell.stderr.on("data", data => {
  console.error(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

powershell.on("close", code => {
  console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`);
});
```

The issue was with access permissions. I got the following error

```
stderr: Import-Module : Process should have elevated status to access IIS configuration data.
```

Comment: Create a shortcut to PS with Admin privilege.  Then run shortcut.

Comment: Check [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/6797). You should be able to start an elevated process from Node.js or you could run with elevated permissions from the getgo. If all you need to do is edited bindings you could also use [`appcmd`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-appcmdexe) which will also likely need elevated permissions.

Comment: You can refer to this link: https://blogs.iis.net/ma_khan/troubleshooting-iis-powershell-module-on-windows-7-rc.